# can flask allow external access to database? it is locking INSERT operations

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I run applications on a server using flask connected to a mysql database.

I want to run scripts to update the data. The only way to do this is to shut down the app, run the script, and restart the app. This seems unnecessary. Apparently any INSERT operation is locked when running a flask application.

What if my flask app is read-only? Is there some way to tell flask not to lock my database?

Interestingly, flask does let me do a DELETE externally. But then I cannot INSERT. Not very helpful. :--(